# ocaml tail-recursive functions

Tags: ocaml, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

I'm running Ocaml using utop, when I run the below function on a very long input:

```
let string_to_list str =
  let rec loop i limit =
    if i = limit then []
    else (String.get str i) :: (loop (i + 1) limit)
  in
  loop 0 (String.length str);;
```

it returns the following error:

```
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

What would be the tail-recursive version of the function?

Comment: Surely, it will not be an `stack overflow` over input of strings of smaller length. What kind of inputs did you try and upon what kind did it overflow? This thing will help you understand, at times... why there is a need for a `tail-recursive` solution over `recursive` ones and this situation is almost the case with every functional language that we will code with. Otherwise, `recursive` style is the most clear, concise and elegant way to specifying solutions.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69574704/2625442

Answer (score 3):

As Jeffrey Scofield noted, your function is not tail-recursive. Converting it to use tail recursion will involve introducing an accumulator argument to your `loop` function.

```ml
let string_to_list str =
  let rec loop i limit acc =
    if i = limit then acc
    else 
      let ch = String.get str i in
      loop (i + 1) limit (ch :: acc)
  in
  loop 0 (String.length str) [] |> List.rev
```

This way all of the necessary information for the evaluation of the function is contained in one stack frame, and the compiler can optimize away all of the previous stack frames.

To provide a bit of a visual in pure text, we look at the non-tail-recursive version of the function, called on `"hello"`.

```
+-----------------------+
| string_to_list "hello"|->
+-----------------------+ |
^      v------------------+
| +--------+
<-|loop 0 5|->
  +--------+ |
  ^      v---+
  | +--------+
  <-|loop 1 5|->
    +--------+ |
    ^      v---+
    | +--------+
    <-|loop 2 5|->
      +--------+ |
      ^      v---+
      | +--------+
      <-|loop 3 5|->
        +--------+ |
        ^      v---+
        | +--------+
        <-|loop 4 5|->
          +--------+ |
          ^      v---+
          | +--------+
          <-|loop 5 5|
            +--------+
```

As we go through, each call needs the information in the previous call. But, if `loop` passes all of the necessary information (that accumulated result list) through arguments, then no iteration of `loop` needs any of the previous calls in order to fully evaluate.

```
     +-----------------------+
     | string_to_list "hello"|
     +-----------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|loop 0 5 []                       |
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|loop 1 5 ['h']                    |
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|loop 2 5 ['e'; 'h']               |
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|loop 3 5 ['l'; 'e'; 'h'].         |
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|loop 4 5 ['l'; 'l'; 'e'; 'h']     |
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|loop 5 5 ['o'; 'l'; 'l'; 'e'; 'h']|
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|List.rev ['o'; 'l'; 'l'; 'e'; 'h']|
+----------------------------------+
                |
                v
+----------------------------------+
|['h'; 'e'; 'l'; 'l'; 'o']         |
+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The `loop` function is not tail recursive. You can see that it applies an operation (`::`) to the return value of the recursive call. This prevents it from being tail recursive. I.e., the recursive call is not at the tail.

**Update**

Here is a tail recursive function to change a string into a list of characters. I hope I'm not doing your homework for you.

```
let string_to_list str =
    let rec loop accum i =
        if i >= String.length str then
            List.rev accum
        else
            loop (String.get str i :: accum) (i + 1)
    in
    loop [] 0
```

As I said in the comment, this is something you absolutelly have to be familiar with to do functional programming. But it's not difficult  once you see the trick.

Fairly often it's necessary to accumulate a list in reverse order, then reverse it at the end. Adding to the end of a list is too slow (it tends to give quadratic complexity).

**Update 2**

Here is an even more efficient tail-recursive version, which doesn't require the List.rev and String.length calls:

```
let string_to_list str =
    let rec loop accum i =
        if i < 0 then
            accum
        else
            loop (str.[i] :: accum) (i - 1)
    in
    loop [] (String.length str - 1)
```

(In fact this is a very good way to get the list of characters, but it doesn't teach the all-important technique of accumulating results backward and reversing at the end. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
How can I make it tail-recursive?

Comment: The age-old trick is to pass an accumulated answer down to the recursive call as a parameter, rather than applyaing an operation the return value. If you don't know this method, it is critical to learn. I'll add it to my answer.