# How can I change user defined type to int?

Tags: ocaml

```
type t=Num of int (* need to change to Num2 of int *)

type e = Num of int
| Add of e*e

let rec intp e : t =
| Num n -> t (n)
| Add (e1, e2) -> int (intp e1) + int (intp e2)
```

I want to add two variable that is user defined type but they can't add user defined types so I cast type using int () but Unbound value int occured. How can I change type t to int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code doesn't has two definitions of `Num`. I'll assume the second one is what you want.

In general the way to extract a value is by pattern matching. Here is a function that returns the int inside a value of your type `e` if it is `Num` and 0 if it is `Add`:

```
let int_val x = match x with Num i -> i | Add _ -> 0
```

You can  use pattern matching in a similar way in your code to extract the int value from `Num i`.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to make code short for viewers and I made a mistake. Thank you for comment

Answer (score 1):

If you want `intp` to return type `t`, you have to use its `Num` constructor. If we run `intp` on an `e` value constructed with `Num2`, we extract its int value with pattern matching and construct a `t` value with `Num`.

Knowing `intp` will eventually return a `t` value, we can use pattern matching on the result of recursively calling `intp` on each of `Add`'s subexpressions to extract the two int values, then add them together and construct a `t` value with `Num`.

```
type t = Num of int

type e = 
  | Num2 of int
  | Add of e * e
 
let rec intp = function
  | Num2 n -> Num n
  | Add (e1, e2) -> 
    let Num n1 = intp e1 in
    let Num n2 = intp e2 in
    Num (n1 + n2)
```

```
# intp @@ Add (Num2 9, Add (Num2 3, Num2 1));;
- : t = Num 13
```

**Further reading**

This has the downside of not being tail-recursive. But it's essentially a binary tree, and [ivg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2625442/ivg) has written a very good [guide to tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69574704/15261315) that includes tail-recursion on trees. It's a heck of a ride, but it might help you take this function to the next level.